# putting together restangular and angularstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am bootstrapping a new angular application.

Will be using Angular JS as MVC and bootstrap, hence angularstrap is a default choice.

Could someone please advice me on the usage of  [angular resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource) vs restangular. I read this SO answer, and it promted me to move with restangular.

The question is how does restangular fits well with angularstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The choice of restangular or angularjs resource has nothing to do with using angularstrap or any other similar UI framework such as [UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

Restangular is used for server communication in a more RESTful manner. Which implies you are free to choose any framework for UI and use the Restangular service for server communication.